# Reset state redux on window reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to investigate how to dispatch action in one case with parameters and without on 'init()' when componentDidMount happened. The problem here that I have two pages,
`overview` and sub router page `edit`
When I switch between this two pages I need to keep state, on `window` reload I need to reset state. When I move from sub page I use `react-router-dom` `this.props.history({pathName: 'overview', state: LATES props I have from overivew})`

The `init` happened on my HOC

```
export default WrappedComponent => class Initializable extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => this.props.init()

    render = () => <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
}
```

Expected solution: 'router path traking' somehow and keep state only for some routes. Or dispose somehow state when switch from `edit` to `overview` but keep it for overview. 
Or add some windows.reload reducer .

any idea?

Expected behavior :
-reset state on window reload

Current behavior:
-keep state when switch between `edit` to `overrivew`
- reset state between another pages
- do not reset state on window reload

***Overview component***

```
export class Overview extends Component {
//just for example
    <div>
    this.props.patients
    this.props.search
    this.props.sort
    ....
    </div>
}
export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    patients: state.patients,
    sort: state.patients.sort,
    search: state.patients.search,
})
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, {location: {state = {}}}) => ({
        init: () =>  dispatch(PatientActions.load(state)),
    })
```

***Edit component***

```
export class Editextends Component {
//just for example

returnToList = () => this.props.history.push({pathname: '/overview', state})
    <div>
    <Button onClick={this.returnToList}>
    this.props.patients
    ....
    </div>
}
export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    patients: state.patients,
})
```

**PatientActions actions**

```
 const load = ({accessToken, ...params} = {}) => async dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: PatientActions.LoadingStarted,
        })

        let response = await api.load({accessToken, ...params})

        dispatch({
            type: PatientActions.ListLoaded,
            response,
        })

        return response
    }
```

**Patient reducer**

```
 export default (actionTypes, initialState = {}) => (state = {
    sort: undefined,
    pageSize: undefined,
    ...initialState,
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ListLoaded:
            let filter = filterSelector({
                ...action,
                sort: action.sort || initialState.sort,
                search: action.search || initialState.search,
            })
            let {response: {result: {totalCount, list}}} = action
            return {
                ...state,
                ...filter,
            }

        case actionTypes.LoadingStarted:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoadingInProgress: true,
            }
    })
```

Comment: You're saying you reload the page and the state doesn't reset? Unless you're persisting it somehow I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Yes when I reload page this does not reset state. 
Look like render happened several time. When move from `edit` page
all state that where in overview kept in redux store.